# How do I select values from a pytorch tensor by index?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I was struggling to figure out how to go about this class problem using pytorch. The question is "select for all i,j the values x[i,j,k] where ind[i,j] = k in a tensor,
the tensor should have shape (10,50)"

```
ind = torch.randint(50,(10,50))
x = torch.randn(10,50,50)
```

Could I do this using `torch.scatter` or `.gather`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `torch.gather`, you just have to expand the dims of your indices:

```
y = torch.gather(x,2,ind[:,:,None]).squeeze(2)
assert y[0] == x[0,0,ind[0][0]]
```

This is because the indices must be the same dimensionality as the input tensor.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I couldn't get it to work as is. I get: 'RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous' wrt to the assert statement. Not exactly sure what the assert statement is doing, could you explain? Could I use torch.unsqueeze to add a dimension to the indices before using torch.gather?

Comment: If you run that assert statement right after your example above it is just proving that the first element of `y` is equal to the indexed value of `x` in the first row/column.